# i need to install a python module through means of a .sh file

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi, archlinux

i need to install a python module with a shell file. i am installing GPIO module for my RPi but i cant' connect the RPi(B+) to the internet. the raspberry pi is running arch linux and is configured to automatically execute 2 programs (main.py and update.sh) which are located on a flash drive. i need to be able to install python modules with update.sh (that's why it's called update.sh). i am rather new to using arch linux and am not confident in my ability to do this yet. i am great-full for any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

If there are Arch Linux ARM packages for the python modules you can put them on the flash drive, mount the flash drive and install them with:
pacman -U /path/to/flashdrive/python-somemodule-0.1-1-armv6.pkg.tar.gz

If there is no Arch package, try downloading the .whl file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi putting it on a flash drive and installing it with pip install /path/to/flashdrive/python-somemodule-0.1-1-py2.py3-none-any.whl